# WPF - Why doesn't Microsoft supply a decent set of most-used controls ?

Tags: wpf, controls

I've been playing with WPF for some months now, and I quite like it.
But one of the things I don't get is why MS doesn't put a little more effort in helping developers by supplying basic controls, and I need to get this off my chest :)

For example, I figure most applications somewhere will need to let you edit some properties - for configuration or whatever.
What would be the most used types in a proprety-grid editor ?

- text
- numbers (byte, float/double, int, etc)
- colors

....etc.

So why isn't there even something as simple as a control to edit numbers ? Like a generic NumericUpDown control that allows you to type in numbers (no text, no pasting invalid input) or spin them up/down according to some given rules (decimal, floating point, min/maxvalue) ?
Why isn't there a generic colorpicker, so people get the same user-experience in every application ?
Why isn't there a standard implementation of a SearchTextBox, a BreadCrumb-control, or all these other standard control types users have gotten accustomed to the last 10 years ?

(..but at least they DID have the time to implement *a generic splashscreen* - because everyone knows that *greatly* increases user-productivity....)

The well-known ideal is always to give people the same user-experience over different applications. So even if some of those controls would be easy to make - it would be preferred to have one version over different applications.

I see people all over the internet trying to do the same stuff over and over again.
Okay, so MS started a WPF Toolkit project on Codeplex that tries to implement some controls, but only did so half-heartedly and is completely dead by now (last update of the roadmap dates back to Mar 21 2009).

The result of this is that a lot of people starting a WPF-project end up spending a lot of time on trying to figure out how to create some generic controls and get really frustrated.

Wasn't the mantra "Developers, developers, developers!" ..?

/Rant

Comment: This is a bit argumentative. Any response would be pure speculation or subjective unless you got an answer from someone on the team that has inside knowledge of the decisions made.

Comment: The [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com)'s planned features lists a NumericUpDown control, maybe you can submit a feature request there to hurry them along?

Comment: As mentioned, the WPF Toolkit is dead. The "planned features" haven't been updated in almost 2 years now.

Answer (score 2):

Because its ridiculously easy to make these in WPF. With WPF and silverlight microsoft's focus is on a core framework that makes many tasks (such as stylable controls) dead simple. Tools are more important than prebuilt controls. They are focusing on the NEXT thing rather than a better Winforms.

Comment: +1 because I think this is the closest we've come so far to a real answer. But though I agree with you on some level, I also think the question has a point with regards to *standard* implementations of these controls. If each developer or team or project is left to roll their own, applications can start looking like, well, *anything*. That certainly doesn't make for a positive, predictable user experience (Unfortunately, I think the answer to *this* is that we're already well on our way down that road. And I don't like it one bit.)

Comment: If it's ridicilously easy then I wonder why there simply is not a single good NumericUpDown control available for free that actually works with different types (byte,int,double) *and* has proper masking *and* proper formatting. Show me a link and I'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: But once again, why would you *want* people to keep reinventing the wheel for such core components ? Why supply a generic splashscreen, but not a standard way to input/edit numbers ? Why *not* want to give users the same user-experience across apps for something as basic as number-editors, color-pickers, breadcrumb-controls, searchtextboxes etc. ?

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy check out the numericupdown control here : http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home ... what's wrong with it ?

Comment: @Basarat - that it doesn't do proper text-masking (you can type your name in the textbox just fine) and doesn't prevent pasting in invalid data.

But this wasn't about getting a NumericUpDown implementation that works, the point is why there's no basic/standard implementation for such basic controls that are used in almost every app.
Why would you want people to keep reinventing the wheel for stuff like that - just create a professional standard implementation, and if people need something different *then* they can start rolling their own version.

Comment: People could write their own combobox as well, but I'm glad there's a default implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think Microsoft - and some people responding here - are forgetting about the most important part of this post :

"*The well-known ideal is always to give people the same user-experience over different applications. So even if some of those controls would be easy to make - it would be preferred to have one version over different applications*"

Just Google Image Search on "WPF Color Picker" ( http://www.google.nl/images?q=wpf+color+picker ) and you'll see this idea go down the drain.

Comment: a winforms color picker would give just as diverse a search : http://www.google.nl/images?q=winforms+color+picker So would a swing color picker : http://www.google.nl/images?q=swing+color+picker people alwasy have and always want more control ... wpf gives you that without getting in the way. Its sort of like we don't do hungarian notation anymore ... times change ... programmers *want* more control. I for one did .. and love wpf

Comment: Uhm, that is because there's also no standard colorpicker for WinForms - so there my case would be the same :) I think that for standard controls that are used by a *lot* of applications, there simply should be a standard version. You want more control, fine, *then* you'll roll your own. But why force *everyone* to reinvent the wheel every time just because one guy *might* need more control ?

Comment: well swing does http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html but the situtation is not improved now is it :) http://www.google.nl/images?q=swing+color+picker

Comment: That must be the most ugly ColorPicker I've ever seen :D

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what i thought at the beginning with WPF..

But afterall, a NumericUpDown is easily created with a cutom usercontrol, same for all the controls you will ever need, you can create it by yourself in (almost) no time, or grab some implementation googling around, and then you can still customize

I think they provided the very basic implementations for the UI elements and leaved all the custom stuff to developers and who need custom stuff, if they would have done a generic color picker, maybe it wouldn't have had all the functionalities that anyone would ever need

Comment: A NumericUpDown is *not* as easily created as you think. Try to build / find a decent implementation that actually works with spinners *and* masked text - and let me know when you do :)

Aside from that, the question is that for the most-used, standard controls - why would you *want* everyone to build them themselves ? The idea should be consistency in user-experience across apps, so why make that so hard for developers ? Hand them the standard controls, and if they need something more - *then* they could 'easily' make it themselves, right ?

Comment: I created a basic NumericUpDown, it's not much code, I haven't tried to make it to work with spinners and masked text though =P. The fact is, if someone needs a control to show a hand of cards for a poker game, can create it. Obviously microsoft won't release a basic "CardHand" user control, that's the same for other controls. Pretty basic one like NumericUpDown (that was part of Windows Form already) should have been released, i know, but maybe it goes against the finality of the product..

Comment: Ofcourse a numericupdown without spinners and masked text is not much code. Those 2 things working *well* are actually what make a good NumericUpDown :)
And I don't consider a cardhand a most-used control. But the webbrowser I'm typing this in uses numericupdown-controls in multiple places, as does my text-editor, programming-ide, photoshop etc.

Comment: My NumericUpDown has a Validator to prevent non-numeric values with a PreviewInput handler, a copy-paste handler, MinValue and MaxValue properties, etc.. I built it as one of my first exercises to understand usercontrols in WPF in a couple of hours, so, really, it isn't THAT hard.. And i can find lots of implementations everywhere, it is just a textbox with 2 buttons, it's not an UI nightmare =)

Comment: Here's my first try with WPF usercontrols, if you're interested:
http://dpaste.com/hold/288946/

as you can see, it's 100 lines XAML + Code, it's not awesome like the ones from Telerik or RadControls, but it works ^^'

Comment: Show me the implementations you find, and I'll tell you what's wrong with them :)
The WPF Extended Toolkit's version doesn't do proper text-masking, most other implementations are unable to work with different value-types (byte, int, double) or use proper formatting.
But to keep repeating myself, the whole point is why you'd WANT people to keep reinventing the wheel for a control that's used in almost every application.

Comment: Thanks for your version.
But it only supports ints, which makes coding it indeed very simple since you don't need to support complex masking for floats/doubles ("0.04", prevent "0.00.4", etc.), string formatting etc.
A useful numericupdown should be able to work with any numeric type, use proper masking, formatting etc.

Comment: They just gave you the bricks, it's up to you to build the house =) (Programmers are soooo lazy sometimes) EDIT: I know my implementation is basic, I've already said that, it works for what i needed to do (integer numeric up-down)

Comment: So basicly I'm asking why there's no standard professional working version to input/edit numbers, you give me something that doesn't work (It simply can't be used to properly edit doubles) and say "It's so simple !" :) The question remains (I'll just keep repeating) : why you'd WANT people to keep reinventing the wheel for a control that's used in almost every application.

Comment: And the answer is also the same: They provided the infrastructure to let you build every user control you'll ever need. (The metaphor of the bricks was self-explaining, imo)

Comment: It just states that they DO make people reinvent the wheel, not why anyone would *want* to do that as it goes against the "keep the user from having to learn new controls with every app he installs" ideal. Do you think they should also not have implemented a radiobutton or combobox ? Because they can be easily made by yourself.

Comment: Can you provide a numeric up down on an HTML page? no. A radio button or checkbox? yes. It's the same with WPF, and no one ever complained about a missing numeric up down control in HTML standard inputs..

Comment: Yes, let's just stick to the 3 features we had in 1992, we'll never need more ! ;) Have you thought about the difference between a text-markup-language and a Desktop User Interface ? They're used in completely different ways with completely different goals and expectations, aside from the fact that HTML is quite some years old now and expectations / features somehow don't quite stay the same in the course of let's say... 20 years :)
So still you're just telling me they DO make people reinvent the weel, not why anyone would WANT to keep people reinventing it.

Comment: If you think so, web and desktop applications are getting closer and closer, and a numeric up down is just a user control, web or desktop app, what's the difference?! anyway, i give up =)

Comment: html != web-application :) and HAH, I WIN ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of 3rd party vendors out there that provide powerful custom controls (editor, navigation, grids, menus, property grids, ...).

It's - in general - cheaper to buy from them than to rewrite your own (when it fits your need of course).

Historically, Microsoft has always encouraged a rich "component-based" eco-system around what they provider out-of-the-box features. This has been true from the beginning of component programming (VBX, OCX, ...) with Microsoft technology. This is arguable, but that's the strategy :-)

Comment: For more complex / less standard controls I can understand that.
But for controls that are used in most of the apps ? Stuff like "edit a number" ? Having to pay money for that (most of those 3rd party control kits cost > $500) seems ridiculous to me.
And it completely goes against the "keep the user experience the same across applications" adagium, since each implementation will be or look slightly different.

Comment: BTW, I suppose you already have taken a look at http://wpf.codeplex.com/ which is a Microsoft project, that contains a bunch of extra features, some of them will be incorporated in next WPF versions.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I wasn't sure it was this one, as he mentions a feb 2009 date, while on the site, the latest release date is feb 2010. There is also an "Extended WPF Toolkit" at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/, not a Microsoft one I believe - and it has a MaskedTextBox BTW :-)

Comment: @Simon: The controls-part of that is the WPF Toolkit for which the roadmap has'nt been changed for almost 2 years now, and the stuff on the roadmap of 2 years ago still hasn't been implemented. The NumericUpDown in the WPF Extended Toolkit doesn't support proper masking or prevent pasting in incorrect data, neither is Brian planning on implementing that.

Comment: Hmmm... I need to start a component business for components below $500 then! just joking :-)

Comment: If you'd offer a professional simple control library (no docking systems or complex stuff like that, just simple basic controls) for $50 I think you'd sell a heck of a lot :)